# Weird SSE output

Tags: c, performance, sse, simd, auto-vectorization

From past one week I am working on SSE instruction and auto vectorization. I am having code written in C which contains long running loops performing interpolation on a very big image. Below is the skeleton code.

```
void Interpolate()
{
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < dstRegionHeight; ++y)
    {
        //Some code to access pixel from bitmap structure. 
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < dstRegionWidth; ++x)
        {
            //Some code to access pixel from bitmap structure.
            for (register unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            {
                //Interpolation arithmetic
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote the above code such that it get successfully auto vectorized by VS 2015 but I haven't get any performance difference after vectorization. ***(Which is expected because of the memory access pattern of the above code and less arithmetic.)*** 
I created the 3 set of compile copy of the above code and tested the execution speed for the same data. Below are the result.

1) Tested code without vectorization and without SSE switch ==> Speed is 1X.
2) No vectorization compile with [`/Arch:SSE2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx) ==> Speed is 10X.
3) Successfully auto vectorized all the code and  `/Arch:SSE2` ==> Speed is 10.5X

The second copy is just compile by enabling SSE2 instruction set the code doesnot get vectorized at all. **How did performance is improved by 10 time just by using SSE2 switch ? without any vectorization**

Note : I performed the test on Intel I3 with 4 GB ram and windows 7 32 bit OS, I also tested the code on 64 bit windows, the results are similar.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimisation enabled in all cases (e.g. `/O2`) ?

Comment: Considering you're using `register`, and no C++ code, I''ll assume the C++ tags was a mistake.

Comment: @PaulR Yes all three sets were compile by turning on all optimisation flags in release mode.

Comment: It depends on how much the compiler can vectorized your code. If it can vectorize most of the main loops then the speedup may be ~4X, not (10.5/10)X like that. Without code nothing can be explained further

Comment: Are you *sure* it didn't auto-vectorize anything in test 2?  But even if not, are you using any FP math?  Especially any math-library functions like `sqrtf`?  When you tested on a 64-bit OS, you were still building 32-bit code, right?  SSE2 is baseline for x86-64.

Comment: According to MS's docs for VS2015, `/Arch:SSE2` is the default if no `/Arch` is specified.  Are you *sure* you compiled the 1x version with optimization enabled?  So you used `/Ox /Arch:IA32` or something?  Is it possible link-time optimization is propagating compile-time constants in your benchmark with some compile options but not others?  **Include the asm for the inner loop for all 3**, because at this point it looks more like your test went wrong or your compiler settings didn't do what you thought.  And/or include the C source to make this a [mcve] we can compile on http://godbolt.org/

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes it didn't vectorized anything in test2 (atleast VS told me this using switch /Qvec-report:2). The original code is not auto-vectorization friendly there is loop data dependency. I am not using any math library the arithmetic just involve bit shifts and multiplication. On testing 64 bit version I compile the code using 64 bit configuration. On testing x86 machine I build the assembly using 32 bit configuration.

Comment: So what *is* different in the compiler-generated asm between the 1x and the 10x version?  This question is un-answerable, because nothing you've included in the question points to a likely explanation.  We need more details.

Comment: @PeterCordes https://godbolt.org/g/wv4uEk

Comment: Godbolt only has CL19 (from Visual Studio 2017), and I don't know how to compile as C instead of C++ with MSVC.  (For gcc / clang it's `-xc`).  But anyway, compiling as C++ with `-Ox`, the asm output is *identical* with `/Ox /arch:IA32` vs. `/Ox /arch:SSE2`.  See the asm-diff pane on this godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/g/nsZotm.  So whatever you're doing, that C source still doesn't explain anything.  Perhaps it compiles differently when there's an outer loop so it runs more than 4 total iterations (which CL19 fully unrolls).

Comment: Also, aliasing analysis may depend on inlining because of `char*` without `restrict`.

Comment: You can help gcc to vectorize your code by storing the result in a temporary and copying it back: https://godbolt.org/g/D1J8Ns Your code looks buggy however -- you are shifting an `unsigned char` to the left before widening the type, thus you will lose the upper bits.